# How to detach process from terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, process, fzf

I want to search for a file with `fzf` and open it. To do so, I've created this simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
result="$(fzf)"
mimeopen "${result}" &
```

When running it from a terminal everything works as expected.
I then want to run this on a key combination in a newly created terminal. To do so I run the command `konsole -e fsearch.sh` (where fsearch is the script).

The terminal is opened and `fzf` works, but when I select the file nothing happens. If I remove the `&` to detach the process it works, but the terminal remains open (as expected), so it would seem the window can't be opened before the script finishes and the process dies, bringing its children with him.

I want the terminal to disappear after `fzf` is done, but the selected file to still open independently.

**I have already tried:**

- `disown`
- `nohup`
- another terminal emulator (`gnome-terminal` and `xterm`)
- using `xdg-open` instead of `mimeopen`

To no avail.

Comment: This might be related: https://serverfault.com/questions/24425/can-i-nohup-screen-an-already-started-process

Comment: It should have work with `nohup`. What was the issue?

Comment: How and where exactly do you set up the shortcut? In your desktop environment (which one?), konsole, or `.bashrc`? If you configure the shortcut in your desktop environment, does the commando work if you use the [Alt][F2] menu to execute your command?

Comment: @Bsquare using `nohup` did not seem to have any effect; the terminal closed without opening other windows. When running from an existing terminal it works.

Comment: @Socowi I have yet to configure a shortcut. I'm testing it by running `konsole -e fsearch.sh` from command line; `fsearch.sh` is a bash script in my `PATH`.

Comment: According to [man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mimeopen) I guess you should use something like `nohup mimeopen -nM "${result}" &`

Comment: My current workaround is to `sleep` for a very small amount of time (0.001 seconds) before ending the script.